correlations and adjusting p-values
I want to determine the correlation and p-value between one variable and all of the others in an R data frame, so I created a correlation matrix with cor_mat, and then cor_get_pval. The relevant p-values were all p<.0001. To test the accuracy, I used cor.test on my one variable and some of the others, individually. I got the same correlation coefficient, but very high p-values (p>.5).
I think the reason for this is that cor_mat doesn't adjust p-values for multiple hypothesis testing, and cor.test does, but then shouldn't the cor_mat p-values generally be higher than the cor.test values? In any event, to minimize the potential for Type I error (which is why p-values get adjusted), I increased the confidence level in cor_mat to 0.9999, and got the same very low p-values. Here is my code:
cor_crime2022_test <- cor_mat(Crime2022_Gini , method = "pearson" , conf.level = 0.9999)

pval <- cor_get_pval(cor_crime2022_test)

cor.test(Crime2022_Gini$TotIncidents , Crime2022_Gini$Gini2022)

Is my thinking about this correct? Should I rely on the p-values in cor_mat or cor.test? Should I be doing something else?

How many variables in the data frame?

40 variables and 1,474 observations

rstatix::cor_mat calls stats::cor.test internally and from my quick test their results indeed match. There is no adjustment going on (I'm on v0.7.2). For what it's worth, changing the confidence level has no impact on P-values, only on confidence intervals.

That sounds like you must have some kind of coding error. Even Bobferroni wouldn't make changes that big.
